# Regular Expression To Substitute A Modified Capture Group

Tags: regex, vb.net

Okay, you RegEx gurus out there, I have one for you.

I have a JSON *OpenAPI* file I need to do some pre-processing on.

I need to replace the *operationId* value with a modified version of the *summary* value.

For example:

**Original JSON** (partial, artificially varied for explanation purposes):

```
"post": {
  "description": "Creates a constituent note.",
  "operationId": "56b76471069a050520297722",
  "summary": "Note (Create)",
  "parameters": [
    ...

"post": {
  "description": "Creates a constituent custom field.",
  "operationId": "578d324da9db950becc619fe",
  "someOtherField": "Some other value",
  "summary": " Constituent custom field (Create)",
  "parameters": [
    ...
```

(Note additional/lower-case words/spaces we need to accommodate and to capitalize the first letter thereof.)

**Required JSON**

```
"post": {
  "description": "Creates a constituent note.",
  "operationId": "NoteCreate",
  "summary": "Note (Create)",
  "parameters": [
    ...

"post": {
  "description": "Creates a constituent custom field.",
  "operationId": "ConstituentCustomFieldCreate",
  "someOtherField": "Some other value",
  "summary": "Constituent custom field (Create)",
  "parameters": [ 
    ...
```

So far, I can get close, with the *operationId* value being exactly the same as the *summary* value. The thing I'm having trouble with is modifying the *summary* value for the *operationId* value.

You can assume that the *summary* field comes after the *operationId* field but not that it comes *immediately* after it. That is, there might be an additional line or lines in there, as per the second example block.

NOTE: I'm using VB.NET so potentially have additional ways to process but I'd like to do it as succinctly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is JSON data, you don't need to do all the work with Regex. You can use a JSON parser if you're not using one already.

Fore the Regex part, you can use the following regex pattern to find and replace the unwanted characters in `summary`:

```
(?:^|\W)+([a-zA-Z]?)
```

Which will get you the first letter of each word preceded by one or more word boundaries.

Using a quick helper function, you can easily convert the input to the desired:

```
Private Function GetOperationIdFromSummary(summary As String) As String
    Const pattern As String = "(?:^|\W)+([a-zA-Z]?)"
    Return Regex.Replace(summary, pattern, Function(m) m.Groups(1).Value.ToUpper)
End Function
```

A complete example that uses [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse the JSON string:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim jsonStr As String = "{
                                 'description': 'Creates a constituent note.',
                                 'operationId': '56b76471069a050520297722',
                                 'summary': 'Note (Create)'
                             }".Replace("'", """")

    Dim jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr)
    Dim summary As String = jsonObj("summary")

    ' Converting the summary to the desired format using the function above.
    Dim operationId As String = GetOperationIdFromSummary(summary)
    jsonObj("operationId") = operationId

    Dim newJsonStr As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj)
    Console.WriteLine(newJsonStr)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oS89R4).

---

As mentioned above, I recommend using a JSON library, but if you want a Regex-only solution, you can use something like this:

```
Dim jsonStr As String = '...

Dim newJsonStr As String =
Regex.Replace(jsonStr, "operationId"":\s*""(.+?)"".+summary"":\s*""(.+?)""",
              Function(m)
                  Dim index As Integer = m.Groups(1).Index - m.Index
                  Dim length As Integer = m.Groups(1).Length
                  Dim summary As String = m.Groups(2).Value
                  Dim operationId As String = GetOperationIdFromSummary(summary)
                  Return m.Value.Remove(index, length).Insert(index, operationId)
              End Function, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

And here's also an [online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8oaHRT).

Hope that helps.